# wake up sleeping daemon by signal SIGQUIT

Tags: c, linux, signals

I have a problem with my daemon program written in C (Linux).
My program firstly is in sleeping process and then should wake up after receiving a signal.
What I should write in `myhandler`?

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

void myhandler(int signal)
{


}
int main(void) {
signal(SIGQUIT,myhandler);

        /* Our process ID and Session ID */
        pid_t pid, sid;

        /* Fork off the parent process */
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* If we got a good PID, then
           we can exit the parent process. */
        if (pid > 0) {
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        /* Change the file mode mask */
        umask(0);

        /* Open any logs here */        

        /* Create a new SID for the child process */
        sid = setsid();
        if (sid < 0) {
                /* Log the failure */
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }



        /* Change the current working directory */
        if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
                /* Log the failure */
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }



        /* Daemon-specific initialization goes here */

        /* The Big Loop */
        while (1) {
           /* Do some task here ... */

           sleep(30); /* wait 30 seconds */
        }
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I should write in `myhandler`?

Empty signal handler function is fine. It interrupts `sleep`. See [`man signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> The `sleep` function is also never restarted if interrupted by a handler, but gives a success return: the number of seconds remaining to sleep.

However, I would advise not disabling the default action for `SIGQUIT`, which is terminate the process and dump core. `SIGINT` may be a better choice.

E.g.:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void signal_handler(int) {}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    if(sleep(60))
        printf("signal received\n");
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./test
^Csignal received
```

Comment: I do not understand, so you are telling that this should work?I do not have to change anything?

Comment: @Krystek102 Yes, added an example for you.